# jQuery mobile plugin popup support

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, jquery-plugins

I'd like to use **http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/popup/** to create a popup.

Here's jquery hosted cdn hosted files: **https://jquerymobile.com/download/**

This as far as I've come **https://jsfiddle.net/hbaecklund/1zoj1pms/2/** Why doesn't it work?

Here's what I tried to create using jquery.

```
$( "head" ).append ('<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" /><script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script><script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>');
$( ".target" ).append('<a href="#popupCloseRight" data-rel="popup" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-inline">Right close button</a><div data-role="popup" id="popupCloseRight" class="ui-content" style="max-width:280px"><a href="#" data-rel="back" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-a ui-icon-delete ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-right">Close</a><p>I have a close button at the top right corner with simple HTML markup.</p></div>');
```

Comment: you have to have jQuery.js loaded before you use jQuery functions. Or you can insert them using Javascript. http://plnkr.co/edit/cRuBsJF6HLEMvtJfPqua?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JSFiddle you have to input your external "css" and "js" files in the left side menu under "External Resources":

[image]

Besides that, JSFiddle asks for https instead of http.

After doing it, [your code works](https://goo.gl/x60KPC).

Answer (score 1):

```
  <!-- Include meta tag to ensure proper rendering and touch zooming -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <!-- Include jQuery Mobile stylesheets -->
  <link rel="stylesheet"   href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">

  <!-- Include the jQuery library -->
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).bind('mobileinit',function(){
      $.mobile.changePage.defaults.changeHash = false;
      $.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false;
      $.mobile.pushStateEnabled = false;
    });
  </script> 

  <!-- Include the jQuery Mobile library -->
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

</head>
  <body>
    <a href="#popupBasic" data-rel="popup" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow  ui-btn-inline" id="pop" data-transition="pop">Basic Popup</a>
      <div data-role="popup" id="popupBasic">
        <p>pop!!</p>
      </div>
```